# ios: disable forward touch event

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

The view tree in my program like this:

```
rootView
  --- subView
```

my problem is how to disable forward touch event from rootView to subView.like:

```
if(shouldForward){
     [rootView passTouchEventToSubView];
}
else{
   //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

[userInteractionEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled)

Comment: if setting userInteractionEnabled=NO, the view will not response any other touch event

Comment: right, instead all touches will be forwarded to rootView. If you want both views to get the events, you have to implement all delegate methods and call the rootViews methods.